# AWS CLI : How to get the API Gateway ID

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

Is there a way/possible on how we can get the API GAteway ID by name or can we iterate the list and return by its name from AWS CLI, i tried the following way and it doesn't return any thing

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query 'items[?name==`TestAPI`].value' --output text --region us-east-1
```

thanks in advance

Updated the list output

```
"items": [
    {
        "id": "5aa9gcij77",
        "name": "JavaLamdba",
        "description": "JavaLamdba",
        "createdDate": 1608225655,
        "apiKeySource": "HEADER",
        "endpointConfiguration": {
            "types": [
                "REGIONAL"
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

```
aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query 'items[?name==`JavaLamdba`].id' --output text --region us-east-1
```

Comment: This is also returning blank, no result

Comment: @JASPHI- Is provided name of api gateway correct? Because this aws cli is working for me for past 6 months in CD automation pipeline.

Comment: Yes @amitd, this is what i'm running  aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query 'items[?name==`JavaLambda`].id' --output text --region us-east-1. Also updated the list that is output in the main question

Comment: @jasphi -  Then command must be like `aws apigateway get-rest-apis --query 'items[?name==`JavaLamdba`].id' --output text --region us-east-1`.  I see typo in the apigateway  name shown in the list output and the one used in your command. Also, Are you using correct aws region? means Have you checked any mismatch in AWS regions of apigateway and the aws cli command?

Comment: Yeah, thanks @amitd, it is the problem with the tilde key cauisng the issue, now the id is displaying

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the expected result

```
> select name, description, created_date from aws.aws_api_gateway_rest_api where name = 'lambda-test';
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
|    name     | description |    created_date     |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------+
| lambda-test | lambda-test | 2019-07-25 09:05:16 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------------
```

https://steampipe.io/